# Capillary force to move a mobile glass rod

Tags: fluid-dynamics, surface-tension, capillary-action

Visualise a glass rod bent to form three sides of a rectangle. A second rod, free to roll on the two parallel sides on the rectangle, constitutes a fourth side of length *l*. If the apparatus is dipped into a glyceric liquid which forms a film in the enclosed rectangle, the mobile rod will be observed to move to decrease the surface area of the film.

The book I'm reading about this experiment in states that if the mobile rod moves by a distance $dx$, the work done is
$$\delta W=F.dx=2\gamma .l.dx$$
where $\gamma$ is the surface tension.

I don't know why there's a factor of 2 in this equation? I understand what it's saying otherwise, but where does the factor of 2 come from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I don't know why there's a factor of 2 in this equation?

The film has two surfaces and, although these surfaces are very close to other (separated only by the thickness of the film), they both independently contribute to the total force.